# can I move a git repo from a subfolder of the folder it should be in

Tags: git, repository

Sorry for the newb question.  I created my git repo in a subfolder of the one I meant to.  There is only one empty file in the respository.  Or should I just kill that and clone the repository from github into the proper place?

Thanks very much in advance.

Best,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

You can clone again your repository as you said, but keep in mind that any local changes that you have not pushed to the remote will be lost: If you did not push them you will not get them back when you clone your repository again.

You can also move your files. If your directory structure is something like this:

/IntendedName/Subfolder/

where the folder containing the repository should have been "IntendedName" instead of "Subfolder", you can just move all the files inside "Sulfolder" to it´s parent (including the hidden directory .git) and then remove "Subfolder". In this case, any local changes will be kept, even if you did not push them.

Comment: You can even do that with local changes and they will be preserved. That you don't get unpushed changes without pushing them seems tautological.

Comment: @pmr You are right, the answer is not clear about what happens with local changes in both cases. I have edited it. Thanks.

Comment: @pmr I agree it´s tautological, but in the question the user said "sorry for the newb question", so i thought it would help to mention it.

Comment: Hi thanks for all the feedback.  The answer is just what I needed to know.  I thought there might be embedded absolute paths somewhere in the .git directory.  Thanks again, Mike